# Suds array of arrays not nesting

Tags: python, soap, suds

Let me preface this by saying that I am still pretty new to SOAP and how things should work.  I'm working with the Vertical Response API.

I'm having trouble getting suds to construct the xml correctly for a request.  Here is some code:

```
from suds.client import Client

url = 'https://api.verticalresponse.com/wsdl/1.0/VRAPI.wsdl'
client = Client(url)
vr = client.service
...
test_list = (
    (
        {
            'name' : 'email_address',
            'value' : login['username'],
        },
        {
            'name' : 'First_Name',
            'value' : 'VR_User',
        }
    ),
    (
        {
            'name' : 'email_address',
            'value' : 'api-support@verticalresponse.com',
        },
        {
            'name' : 'First_Name',
            'value' : login['username'],
        },
    ),
)

# sid and cid are correctly retrieved prior to this point
print "Sending test message..."
vr.sendEmailCampaignTest({
    'session_id' : sid,
    'campaign_id' : cid,
    'recipients' : test_list,
})
```

In this context login['username'] is just an email address.

That code raises this error:

```
suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'Application failed during request deserialization: Too many elements in array. 4 instead of claimed 2 (2)
```

Here is the the definition of sendEmailCampaignTest:
http://developers.verticalresponse.com/api/soap/methods/campaigns/sendemailcampaigntest/

Here is the xml that logging outputs.  **This XML is incorrect and doesn't work** (I removed the session_id and list_id for display here):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
DEBUG:suds.client:headers = {'SOAPAction': u'"VR/API/1_0#sendEmailCampaignTest"', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'}
ERROR:suds.client:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns3="http://api.verticalresponse.com/1.0/VRAPI.xsd" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns4="VR/API/1_0" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns0:Body>
      <ns4:sendEmailCampaignTest>
         <args xsi:type="ns3:sendEmailCampaignTestArgs">
            <session_id xsi:type="ns1:string">redacted</session_id>
            <campaign_id xsi:type="ns1:int">redacted</campaign_id>
            <recipients xsi:type="ns3:ArrayOfNVDictionary" ns2:arrayType="ns3:NVDictionary[2]">
               <item>
                  <name xsi:type="ns1:string">email_address</name>
                  <value xsi:type="ns1:string">email@example.com</value>
               </item>
               <item>
                  <name xsi:type="ns1:string">First_Name</name>
                  <value xsi:type="ns1:string">VR_User</value>
               </item>
               <item>
                  <name xsi:type="ns1:string">email_address</name>
                  <value xsi:type="ns1:string">api-support@verticalresponse.com</value>
               </item>
               <item>
                  <name xsi:type="ns1:string">First_Name</name>
                  <value xsi:type="ns1:string">email@example.com</value>
               </item>
            </recipients>
         </args>
      </ns4:sendEmailCampaignTest>
   </ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
DEBUG:suds.client:http failed:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Application failed during request deserialization: Too many elements in array. 4 instead of claimed 2 (2)
</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am porting my script based on the following ruby script (provided by Vertical Response):

```
test_list = [
           [{
              'name' => 'email_address',
              'value' => $username
            },
            {
              'name' => 'First_Name',
              'value' => 'VR_User'
            }
           ],
           [{
              'name' => 'email_address',
              'value' => 'api-support@verticalresponse.com'
            },
            {
              'name' => 'First_Name',
              'value' => $username
            }
           ]
          ]
print "Sending test message...\n"
temp0 = vr.sendEmailCampaignTest({
                                 'session_id' => sid,
                                 'campaign_id' => cid,
                                 'recipients' => test_list,
                               })
```

It outputs the following xml.  **This XML is correct and does work** (I removed the session_id and list_id):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <env:Body>
    <n1:sendEmailCampaignTest xmlns:n1="VR/API/1_0"
        env:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <args xmlns:n2="http://api.verticalresponse.com/1.0/VRAPI.xsd"
          xsi:type="n2:sendEmailCampaignTestArgs">
        <session_id xsi:type="xsd:string">redacted</session_id>
        <campaign_id xsi:type="xsd:int">redacted</campaign_id>
        <recipients xmlns:n3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
            xsi:type="n3:Array"
            n3:arrayType="n2:NVDictionary[2]">
          <item xsi:type="n3:Array"
              n3:arrayType="n2:NVPair[2]">
            <item>
              <name xsi:type="xsd:string">email_address</name>
              <value href="#id9496430"></value>
            </item>
            <item>
              <name xsi:type="xsd:string">First_Name</name>
              <value xsi:type="xsd:string">VR_User</value>
            </item>
          </item>
          <item xsi:type="n3:Array"
              n3:arrayType="n2:NVPair[2]">
            <item>
              <name xsi:type="xsd:string">email_address</name>
              <value xsi:type="xsd:string">api-support@verticalresponse.com</value>
            </item>
            <item>
              <name xsi:type="xsd:string">First_Name</name>
              <value href="#id9496430"></value>
            </item>
          </item>
        </recipients>
      </args>
    </n1:sendEmailCampaignTest>
    <value id="id9496430"
        xsi:type="xsd:string"
        env:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">address@example.com</value>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I understand that the error is in the construction of recipients.  It should contain two items, each that contain two items but my python script using suds is setting it up to contain four unnested items.  So my question is how can I get suds to correctly construct the xml?

edit: What I've tried:

```
>>> url = 'https://api.verticalresponse.com/wsdl/1.0/VRAPI.wsdl'
>>> client = Client(url)
>>> args = client.factory.create('ns0:sendEmailCampaignTestArgs')  
>>> args
(sendEmailCampaignTestArgs){
   session_id = None
   campaign_id = None
   recipients = 
      (ArrayOfNVDictionary){
         _arrayType = ""
         _offset = ""
         _id = ""
         _href = ""
         _arrayType = ""
      }
 }
```

It appears to me that the ArrayOfNVDictionary is not being constructed correctly by suds (it doesn't have an actual array element that would hold NVDictionary's), any help with figuring that you would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of SOAP is that remote method calls and arguments should look like native methods and objects of your language of choice.

In order to avoid mistakes, always use specific SOAP types like showed in this (untested) snippet:

```
>>> recipient_list = [ 
...     ('root@eruditorum.org', 'Enoch'), 
...     ('billg@microsoft.com', 'Bill'), 
... ]
>>> client = suds.client.Client('https://api.verticalresponse.com/wsdl/1.0/VRAPI.wsdl')
>>> args = client.factory.create('ns0:sendEmailCampaignTestArgs')
>>> for email, first_name in recipient_list:
...     recipient = client.factory.create('ns0:NVDictionary')
...     recipient['email_address'] = email
...     recipient['First_Name'] = first_name
...     args.recipients.append(nvdict)
>>> args.session_id = sid
>>> args.campaign_id = cid
>>> client.service.sendEmailCampaignTest(args)
```

IMHO, explicit code like above is cleaner and easier to maintain.

Of course you can ignore my advice, in this case I guess `test_list` should look like:

```
test_list = [ 
    { 
        'email_address': 'josh@cartme.com', 
        'First_Name': 'Josh' },
    },
    { 
        'email_address': 'josh.cartme@gmail.com', 
        'First_Name': 'Josh' },
    },
]
```

Comment: Ok so when I try something like that it gives me: AttributeError: ArrayOfNVDictionary instance has no attribute 'append'  (I also changed it to args.recipients.append(recipient) rather than append(nvdict).  Do you have any ideas on that?

Comment: @joshcartme: in an ideal world args.recipients should look like an array, but SOAP is a very messy standard, sometimes suds don't understand some WSDLs. Try `args.recipients = []` before the loop.

Comment: Hmm, when I put args.recipients = [] it gives me the following error: suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'Not an ARRAY reference.  I also tried your other suggestion of a way to construct test_list and it produced the same error.  Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @joshcartme: looking at the ruby generated request, I would try list of lists of `client.factory.create('ns0:NVPair')`

Comment: I think I tried the NVPair as well but it didn't work either.  You probably could use the WSDL and make up a random cid (numeric) and sid (alphanumeric).  It wouldn't actually work of course but you could test out syntax.  I am at a loss, gonna pick it up again on Monday.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I guess suds is not dealing well with this WSDL - may be the SOAP version is not supported. I've migrated from verticaresponse to mailchimp, so I don't have an account to test anymore. BTW, mailchimp API is based in JSON, and there is a couple of good modules for interfacing.

Comment: I was looking at mailchimp but the client I am working with is a nonprofit so the vertical response pricing is much better.  You could probably test the WSDL with a bogus cid and sid to get the syntax right, because the error is occurring before the request is sent i believe.  Then if it was right it would probably return that the cid/sid were incorrect or something.  You can also create a free account at vertical response and then ask that they enable api access here: http://developers.verticalresponse.com/api-request-form/ but I totally understand if you don't want to do that.  Thanks!

Comment: I edited the end of my question with what I tried, would you agree that the output that I am given looks incorrect?

Comment: @joshcartme: the WSDL contains type names with `[]`, could it be the problem?

Comment: I've been talking to the maintainer of suds and apparently I'm running into a bug in suds.  He actually recommended that I always use python structs with suds rather than using client.factory.create.  I will update the question if I figure it out.

Comment: @joshcartme: shame on me, exactly the opposite of what I told you.

Comment: no worries, what you said made sense but I guess suds has better support for python structs than using client.factory.create()